# How do I remove specific text from a text file?

Tags: java

I've got a list of customers containing: Customer ID, Customer Name, Customer Phone and Customer Email. I'm looking to be able to remove a customer from a list on a text file by typing in the customers Name and/or ID. Here's what I've currently got:

```
  public static List<Customer> removeCustomer (List<Customer> customers)  throws IOException {
  File inputFile = new File("customers.txt");    
  File tempFile = new File("tempcustomers.txt");

  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
  BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));

 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Enter Customer ID");
  String newCustomerId = scanner.nextLine();
  System.out.println("Enter Customer Name");
  String customerName = scanner.nextLine();

  String currentLine;

    while((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {

      if(currentLine.contains(newCustomerId) 
         && (currentLine.contains(customerName))) continue;

     writer.write(currentLine);


 writer.close();
 boolean successful = tempFile.renameTo(inputFile);
 System.out.println(successful);
    }
 return customers;
}
```

Any help would be amazing.. Thanks.

Comment: What does this have to do with `list`?

Comment: What is wrong with what you've currently got?

Comment: It's not deleting the customers from the customers.txt file. @Scott Hunter

Comment: consider looking into the `\b` escape character which is used as a backspace. you could also try re-writing the text file with a substring up to that customer, and a substring after that customer.

Comment: well for starter this code fails. You are closing the writer stream after the first write (I believe you are missing a } after that first write and should remove the one before the return). Second you are reading a line (so something that ends with \n but are never writing it back to your output. Third I don't have a clue as to why you are passing a list of Cutomer Obects and returning that exact same list (it's never altered). And finally, you should really close the reader stream at some point.

Comment: I'm quite obviously not and expert and still learning... Thanks though for the help.. @user1909791

Answer (score 0):

As @user1909791 has already mentioned, you are closing the write after your first read. This is what you should have:

```
while((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    if(currentLine.contains(newCustomerId) 
              && (currentLine.contains(customerName))) continue;

     writer.write(currentLine);
}

writer.close();
reader.close();

// Delete the current customers.txt file then rename the
// tempcustomers.txt File to customers.txt...
boolean successful = false;
if (inputFile.delete()) { successful = tempFile.renameTo(inputFile); }

System.out.println(successful);
...........................................
...... code to refill customers List ......
...........................................
return customers;
```